# What does this symbol mean in pseudo code?

Tags: pseudocode

I'm coding a fusion_sort :

```
input  ː two tabs sorted A and B
output : one sorted tab trié which contains element of A and B 
function fusion(A[1, …, a], B[1, …, b])
  if A is the empty tab
          return B
  if B is the empty tab
          return A
  if A[1] ≤ B[1]
          return A[1] :: fusion(A[2, …, a], B)
  else
          return B[1] :: fusion(A, B[2, …, b])
```

And I don't know what does this line mean :

```
return A[1] :: fusion(A[2, …, a], B)
```

Especially this symbol :

```
::
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the ["cons" operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons).

```
1 :: [2, 3, 4]
```

would give

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It adds the left operand to the head of the list. It's often used in linked list implementations because it's so fast to add to the head of a linked list.

Note a little down the Wikipedia page is the bit:

> (A good example is the :: operator in ML, Scala, F# and Elm or the : operator in Haskell, which adds an element to the beginning of a list.)

---

And `A[2, …, a]` looks like it might be a "slice operator" maybe? In Python, that would be written as `A[1:]`. It just drops the head of the list.

The algorithm described here seems similar to a non-generalized [`map`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) function. `map` takes the head off the list, does an operation on it, cons' it back on the front, then calls itself on the tail of the list. That seems to be what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks a lot !

So, it adds the left term(s) and the right term(s) in a unique tab ?

Comment: @Segfault Not sure what a "tab" is in this context, but it prepends the left operand onto the right operand.